# How are browserslist queries combined in a multi-line browserslist configuration?

Tags: node.js, browser, babeljs, autoprefixer

[Browserslist documentation](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/blob/31dcf022c1673d4b782440fdb997cd83898dfd70/README.md) gives this example config:

```
{
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

How are these lines combined into a single query? [Query composition](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/blob/31dcf022c1673d4b782440fdb997cd83898dfd70/README.md#query-composition) names three operators: `or`, `and`, and `not`, but the documentation does not say which, if any, is used to combine the queries in a config. How are these queries interpreted? I want to know the matching browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End of line is used as union combiner

[parse config content](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/blob/master/index.js#L407)

Answer (score 2):

This is my understanding of why it's the **Union** type from the docs
[image]

Comment: and based on my testing it's the Union as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it uses the **union** combiner

[image]

Comment: Hi Matiishyn, thanks for your reply. Do you remember why you think it's a union? I didn't have time to investigate, and I assumed it was a union, but that's why I asked here :)